# Facebook Like Button is not displaying

Tags: php, html, facebook, button, facebook-like

I want to put facebook like button of my fb page on website. I am using iframe, when I place this i frame in html file then it works, but when I place it in php file then it doesn't display anything. please help me to solve it, Thanks a lot !

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpoetrypoint.tk&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYourPoetryPoint&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not understand what is your problem.

Try the following PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>

<!-- Without echo or print -->

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpoetrypoint.tk&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYourPoetryPoint&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<?php

//With echo

echo '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpoetrypoint.tk&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
echo '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYourPoetryPoint&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';

//With print

print('<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpoetrypoint.tk&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
print('<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYourPoetryPoint&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output]